# By minimizing the function $\phi(s,t) = \frac{1}{2} \mid\mid \textbf{b} - (s\textbf{a}_1 + t\textbf{a}_2) \mid\mid^2$, find a for

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Suppose $\textbf{a}_1$ and $\textbf{a}_2$ are linearly independent vectors, $L = \text{span} \ \{{\textbf{a}_1, \textbf{a}_2}\}$, and $\textbf{b}$ is a vector not in $L$. By minimizing the function $\phi(s,t) = \frac{1}{2} \mid\mid \textbf{b} - (s\textbf{a}_1 + t\textbf{a}_2) \mid\mid^2$, find a formula for the projection of $\textbf{b}$ onto the subspace $L$.

I know the answer is the following: if $\textbf{A} = [\textbf{a}_1 \textbf{a}_2]$, then $\textbf{P} = \textbf{A}(\textbf{A}^* \textbf{A})^{-1}\textbf{A}^*$.

I suppose I am looking for the vector in $L$ which is closest to $\textbf{b}$.

\begin{align}
\phi(s,t) &= \frac{1}{2} \mid\mid \textbf{b} - (s\textbf{a}_1 + t\textbf{a}_2) \mid\mid^2\\
&= \frac{1}{2}<\textbf{b} - s\textbf{a}_1 - t\textbf{a}_2, \textbf{b} - s\textbf{a}_1 - t\textbf{a}_2>\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \{<\textbf{b}, \textbf{b}> -s<\textbf{b}, \textbf{a}_1> -t<\textbf{b}, \textbf{a}_2> \ ... + \ 6 \ \text{other terms???}\}
\end{align}

Normal equations: $\textbf{A}^* \textbf{A}\textbf{x} = \textbf{A}^* \textbf{b}$.

$\nabla \phi = \textbf{A}^* (\textbf{A}\textbf{x} - \textbf{b}) = 0 \ (\text{set equal to zero})$.

$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial s} = \ ?$

$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = \ ?$

$\textbf{A}^* \textbf{A} \pmatrix{s \\ t} = \textbf{A}^* \textbf{b}$.

If $\textbf{A}^* \textbf{A}$ is invertible, then $\pmatrix{s \\ t} = (\textbf{A}^* \textbf{A})^{-1}\textbf{A}^*\textbf{b}$.

$\textbf{A} = \pmatrix{\textbf{a}_1 \ \textbf{a}_2}$.

Null space of $\textbf{A} = \{\textbf{x} \mid \textbf{A}\textbf{x} = \textbf{0}\}$.

Null space of $\textbf{A}^*\textbf{A}$ is the null space of $\textbf{A}$.

$s\textbf{a}_1 + t\textbf{a}_2 = \pmatrix{\textbf{a}_1 \ \textbf{a}_2} \pmatrix{s \\ t}$.

$\textbf{A}(\textbf{A}^* \textbf{A})^{-1}\textbf{A}^*\textbf{b}$ is the closest vector to $\textbf{b}$ in $L$, and we denote it $P_L \textbf{b}$.

I'm trying to fill in the gaps and connect the ideas of these statements to see how this answer was obtained.

Answer (score 1):

Write $\phi_b: \mathbb{R}^2 \to L$ as $\phi_b(x) = {1 \over 2} \|Ax-b\|^2$.
Then, given $b$, we define $P(b) = Ax_b$, where $x_b$ solves $\min_x \phi_b(x)$ (implicitly we are hoping that a solution exists and is unique).

If you expand $\phi_b$ you get
$\phi_b(x) = {1 \over 2}x^T A^T A x -(A^Tb)^T x + b^Tb$, from which we see that
${\partial \phi_b(x) \over \partial x} = (A^T(Ax-b))^T$. (Compute $\phi_b(x+h)-\phi_b(x)$ and look at the terms linear in $h$.)

Since $\phi_b$ is convex and differentiable, we have that $x_b$ is a minimizer **iff** ${\partial \phi_b(x_b) \over \partial x} = 0$.

Since $A$ has full rank, we see that $A^TA$ is invertible, and so
$A^T(Ax_b-b) = 0$ **iff** $A^T A x_b = A^T b $ **iff** $x_b = (A^T A)^{-1} A^T b$.

Hence we have $P(b)  = A (A^T A)^{-1} A^T b$.